# How do you make an Android "Home" shortcut bypass the app it's point to's history?

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut

I have an app that allows you to create Home "shortcuts" to a specific `Activity`. It turns out that some of my users will use the app, hit the home key to go do something else, then use one of the shortcuts to jump back to that Activity. Since the app is still in memory it just opens the new `Activity` on top of the others and the "Back" key will take them back through the whole history. What I'd like to have happen is if they use a shortcut then to effectively kill the history and have the back key just exit the app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, set up the [taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) in the Manifest to make the `Activity` run as a different "task":

```
<activity
        android:taskAffinity="" 
        android:name=".IncomingShortcutActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.App.Shortcut"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then, when building the shortcut, set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags. Something like:

```
// build the shortcut's intents
final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), ".IncomingShortcutActivity"));
shortcutIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_STOPID, Integer.toString(this.stop_id));
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
// Sets the custom shortcut's title
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, custom_title);
// Set the custom shortcut icon
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.bus_stop_icon));
// add the shortcut
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify it little bit? Where the code should go, IncomingShortcutActivity? Who will handle broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Intent.FLAG_NEW_TASK` to the Intent.

Comment: Well, that got me part of the way there at least. Thanks