# How to call the Shortcut menu like a long press on the home screen

Tags: android, menu, shortcut, picker

Im tyring to figure out how to bring up the shortcut assign menu (the menu you get when you long press the screen for the Home launcher.  I cant seem to find anything on this and need to make shortcuts for both applications and be able to do direct dial and saved navigations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a ContextMenu. [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for how to add ContextMenu to your applications. Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.

Comment: Im already using a contextMenu what Im trying to do is populate it with the default shortcut menu items, for example when you press and bring up the contextMenu on the home screen you get the following (at least on my Captivate I know its different depending on whats installed): Applications, Activities, Bookmark, Contact, Direct Dial, Directions & Navigation, etc.  I can bring this menu up with ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT but cant add my options to it and thats where Im having trouble

Answer (score 0):

To add a Shortcut to the Androids home-screen, you can use some of the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978172/how-do-you-make-an-android-home-shortcut-bypass-the-app-its-point-tos-history).

I'm not sure how to do this for the Dailer or Google Maps, but [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692859/creating-home-screen-browser-shortcuts-from-android-app) of how to do it for the Browser. It might help you.